# How 2 to merge two functions in JavaScript for same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below code is working fine, but i want merge checked and click functions in single function. Is it possible?

```
$(function () {
  if($("#enablepromo0").is(":checked"))   
     $("#PromoPanel").show(300);
  else
    $("#PromoPanel").hide(300);
});
$(function () {
   $("#enablepromo0").click(function () {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $("#PromoPanel").show(300);
        } else {
          $("#PromoPanel").hide(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: *meagre* ??? No idea what that is.

Comment: @connexo clearly 'merge'

Comment: Put your HTML in the question as well to get answers, otherwise we are guessing a bit here

Comment: No need for two document ready functions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the change event and trigger it, it can then detect the current state of the checkbox.  I altered the code to toggle a class instead to avoid a "flash" initially.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#enablepromo0").on('change', function() {
    let isChecked = !this.checked;
    $("#PromoPanel").toggleClass("hidden", isChecked, {
      duration: 300
    });
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```css
.panel {
  border: solid lime 1px;
  background: #ddffdd;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check to show: <input type="checkbox" id='enablepromo0' />
<div class="container">
  <div id="PromoPanel" class="panel hidden">
    <h2>Hi There</h2>Get stoked</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working fine without adding  hidden class but loss animation :(

Answer (score 0):

both function do the same job so i changed something to show an alert:

```js
$(function () {  

$("#enablepromo0").click(function () {
     alert("dddddd")
  if($("#enablepromo0").is(":checked"))   
     $("#PromoPanel").show(300);
  else
    $("#PromoPanel").hide(300); 
        });

 


  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id='enablepromo0'/>
<div id="PromoPanel" style="border: 1px solid  red; width:50px; heigth:50px; display:none;">uuu</div>
```

Comment: But i want same job for both function.

Answer (score 0):

Move the code to its own function and call as required:

```
function showHide() {
  if ($("#enablepromo0").is(":checked"))   
     $("#PromoPanel").show(300);
  else
    $("#PromoPanel").hide(300);
}

$(function () { 
  showHide();

  $("#enablepromo0").click(function () {
    showHide();
  });
});
```

Comment: You could also use `$("#enablepromo0").click(showHide);` but this is not a bad solution.

Comment: Yes, there's plenty of variants.  I was keeping it relatively simple as it appears OP doesn't know about creating reusable functions.  There are enough questions on SO asking about things like `.click(myfunc())` vs `.click(myfunc)` that in some cases it's better to build up from the basics without adding additional potential confusion.