# Run jQuery document ready function a second time onclick?

Tags: jquery, onclick, document-ready

I am sorry, I know this might be a very basic question. 
I have a document ready jQuery function, that has various different functions inside itself. 
This function is triggered on every pageload.

Is there somehow a possibility, to run this function onclick again, without realoading the page? 
Is it possible to name the function, and then trigger it again onclick?

e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// doing a lot of stuff on DOM ready
});

$( "button" ).click(function() {
// do all the stuff again onclick without reloading the page
});
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You want to execute certain code on page load as well as on button click?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59126107/2181514

Comment: @BvdL exactly. I have a "huge" document ready function, which needs to be run document ready. But I also want the possibility to run that function on buttonclick again.

Comment: @арнонюм In that case `uday8486`'s answer is what you want.

Comment: @BvdL Thanks man! I read the answer already and will give this a try. Thank's to uday8486 as well. I upvoted and will mark it as accepted answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to put the common functionality into a function and call it on load and on click like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // doing a lot of stuff on DOM ready
    DoSomething();  // Called on the Document Ready.


   $( "button" ).click(function() {
     // do all the stuff again onclick without reloading the page

      DoSomething();  // Called on the button click.
   });


});

function DoSomething() {
   // doing a lot of stuff
}
```

Hope that helps.